# Resize textbox and form size according to Text Length

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, textbox

How can I automatically increase/decrease TextBox and Windows Form size according to text Length?

Comment: Use the Autosize property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.autosize.aspx

Comment: @Jodrell this doesn't change the width of a TextBox, only the height.

Answer (score 10):

You can try overriding the [OnTextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.ontextchanged.aspx) event, then changing the [Width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.width.aspx) depending on the size of the text.

```
protected override OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics())
    {
        SizeF size = g.MeasureString(Text, Font);
        Width = (int)Math.Ceiling(size.Width);
    }
    base.OnTextChanged(e);
}
```

Comment: I've never tried it on a TextBox TextChanged either ;) but it works for me when I'm resizing a UserControl based on an inner Label's Text.

Comment: i always followed above answer what I proposed. I never worked on Override

Comment: @rapsalands without overriding, all `OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)` does is fire the events. They do exactly the same thing so it'll still work.

Comment: no no...i know it will still work and i was just saying i have not worked on override techniques ever. I am kinda new in this field, got to learn and explore a lot. I liked your technique and that's why added this question in my favorites so I can refer it anytime. Thanks.

Comment: @rapsalands it certainly has its benefits :) a good field to learn. cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it will also work...

Here I have taken 100 as minimum width of textbox. "txt" is TextBox.

```
const int width = 100;

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Font font = new Font(txt.Font.Name, txt.Font.Size);

    Size s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(txt.Text, font);
    if (s.Width > width)
    {
        txt.Width = s.Width;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is better solution.
Scenario is: I have a textbox that Filled on form (usercontrol). So, I want to change Form Height each time number of line in textBox change, but its height is not less than MinHeight (a constant)

```
private void ExtendFormHeight()
        {
            int heightChanged = txtText.PreferredSize.Height - txtText.ClientSize.Height;
            if (Height + heightChanged > MinHeight)
            {
                Height += heightChanged;
            }
            else
            {
                Height = MinHeight;
            }
        }
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Any ideas on how you would do this for a text block? I am passing in a set string from my code.

Answer (score -2):

set width to Auto in properties