# How to scroll specific controls with a HScrollBar In Windows Forms C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with 3 different controls in it, a Panel, a user control, and a button.

The form should work like this:
The Panel Displays The user controls, the button1, adds another user control to the panel, and the user controls display different information.

The problem here is that I need to put a scroll bar (Horizontal) in the panel, so the user can view all the user controls, but I need to move all the user controls (no matter if there are 100 or more), but without moving the button1.

I have tried usingthe form property of AutoScroll, but it moves all the controls inside the form.

Comment: then place `button1` outside of scrolling panel?

Comment: You can move the button in place with the keyboard instead of the mouse so it won't be nested.

Comment: Maybe a "View Port" would be better than a Panel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092215/microsoft-vsrollbar-behavior-or-bug-with-touch-screen-windows-forms/39157985 - is that what you want?